# IIS 6.0 preventing "PUT" & "DELETE" method types on WCF 4.0 web service calls (403 Forbidden)

Tags: wcf, iis-6

I am a developer trying to assist my server admin in figuring out how to get this issue corrected.

But I have an app that is using WCF 4.0 configure-less setup to make RESTful webservices calls.  Everything works fine locally but when pushed to my server all PUT and DELETE requests return a 403 forbidden error.

After searching around I've been unable to find anything that seems to work, and I'm not sure if there is some logs that would help figure this out, I'm not a server guy and apparently neither is my "server guy". So any tips on where to point him or what might be causing this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried adding the verbs to to the appropriate handler on IIS 6. Check this link: http://www.wiibart.com/enable-delete-put-merge-verbs-in-iis5-iis6-fo (OR) http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/4c840252-fab7-427e-a197-7facb6649106.mspx?mfr=true

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You would need to add the verbs to the appropriate handler on IIS 6. The below links explain on how to achieve it.

Steps as below:
1. Right click the Virtual Directory in IIS

2. Select 'Properties'
3. Click 'Configuration...'
4. Search for .svc in the 'Application Extensions' list
5. Select '.svc'  (if this is not present, then you need to add it by clicking Add and using the same path for the executable as is used for the .aspx extension)
6. Click 'Edit ...'
7. In the 'Verbs' list select 'All Verbs'

Links:

1. [MSDN Forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/624e1fc2-f878-4740-84d3-b67096d4d4b0/deploy-project-help-config-iis-6-putdelete-http-verb)
2. [Setting Application mapping on IIS 6](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/4c840252-fab7-427e-a197-7facb6649106.mspx?mfr=true)

Comment: The link to enable PUT and DELETE is no longer valid.

Comment: Because your answer was no longer valid, now that you have updated it. I've reversed my voting.