# Asp.net MVC Web Api Http put and delete requests failing

Tags: iis-6, asp.net-web-api

I am using Asp.net MVC 4 **Web Api** project. MY application uses mvc to implement a web site. It makes http requests to the web api to implement server functionality.

Regular page requests to controllers work fine and it is able to display web pages. The application is able to make **get** and **post** requests to the api. But when it tries to to **put** or **delete** web requests it gets

**"Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 501 (Not Implemented) "**

The application is hosted on iis 6.

The application works when running a local cassani server instance and is able to make **put** and **delete** requests, but as soon as the application is executed from **iis** it doesn't work as expected.

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10553575/iis-6-0-preventing-put-delete-method-types-on-wcf-4-0-web-service-calls-4 ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I tried all the suggestions from the comment above and none of them worked.

I had to add the ASP.NET 4.0 dll to the Wildcard mappings in the Configuration area on the Home Directory tab.  That worked for me.  Remember to uncheck the "Verify file exists" checkbox.

EDIT: I posted a blog on the exact process to make this happen here: http://www.proworks.com/blog/2012/11/14/how-to-fix-aspnet-mvc-web-api-http-put-and-delete-requests-failing/

Comment: Strange. I tried this fix and it worked on one server but not another. Both are identical in setup. On the server which didn't work, a HTTP DELETE gives a 404 error. GET/POST requests are fine. Any ideas?