# HTTP PUT not allowed in ASP.NET Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, iis-7.5

On my Web API project, I cannot perform an `HTTP PUT` to my resources. I've read through [some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10906411/asp-net-web-api-put-delete-verbs-not-allowed-iis-8) [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11727525/asp-net-mvc-web-api-http-put-and-delete-requests-failing) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9854602/asp-net-web-api-405-http-verb-used-to-access-this-page-is-not-allowed-how) [on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10099270/asp-net-web-api-returns-404-for-put-only-on-some-servers?rq=1) [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12136143/put-and-delete-returns-404-for-asp-net-webapi-in-windows-2008-server-iis-7-and-7?rq=1) [problem](http://geekswithblogs.net/michelotti/archive/2011/05/28/resolve-404-in-iis-express-for-put-and-delete-verbs.aspx) and I've followed the recommended advice.

First off, I uninstalled WebDAV completely on my machine (Windows 7 64-bit) and subsequently rebooted my machine.

Secondly, the WebDAV handlers were specified as removed in my `web.config` and the `HTTP PUT` verb was specified as being allowed for the Extensionless URL Handler.

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="false">
  <remove name="WebDAVModule"/>
</modules>

<handlers>
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
  <remove name="WebDAV"/>
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0"
       path="*."
       verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS"
       type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler"
       resourceType="Unspecified"
       requireAccess="Script"
       preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
  <add name="AttributeRouting" path="routes.axd" verb="*" type="AttributeRouting.Web.Logging.LogRoutesHandler, AttributeRouting.Web" />
</handlers>
```

I even tried adding the ISAPI Extensionless URL Handler (32-bit and 64-bit) and changing my application from the integrated pipeline App Pool to the classic App Pool.

```
<add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit"
      path="*."
      verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS"
      modules="IsapiModule"
      scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll"
      preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32"
      responseBufferLimit="0" />
<add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit"
      path="*."
      verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS"
      modules="IsapiModule"
      scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll"
      preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64"
      responseBufferLimit="0" />
```

I'm currently using [Thinktecture IdentityModel](http://nuget.org/packages/Thinktecture.IdentityModel) to enable Cross Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) support. For my sanity, I've gone with the nuclear option of enabling everything to make sure the `HTTP PUT` is actually allowed.

```
config.RegisterGlobal(httpConfig);

config.ForAllResources()
      .ForAllOrigins()
      .AllowAllMethods()
      .AllowAllRequestHeaders();
```

The [Attribute Routing](http://attributerouting.net/) NuGet package is configured to pick up all routes from the current assembly and any subtypes of `ApiController`.

```
config.AddRoutesFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
config.AddRoutesFromControllersOfType<ApiController>();
```

My resource has the `PUT` attribute properly specified as well.

```
[PUT("/API/Authenticate/Link/{key}/{identifier}")]
public Boolean LinkUser(Guid key, String identifier) { ... }
```

Every resource I look up on this matter recommends the same exact thing: Uninstalling WebDAV, disabling the WebDAV handlers and making sure that the Extensionless URL handler is properly configured. I've done all that and it **still** doesn't work.

In fiddler, I'm getting the following:

```
PUT https://localhost/Test/API/Authenticate/Link/Foo/Bar

{"Message":"The requested resource does not support http method 'PUT'."}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Should that attribute be an `[HttpPut]`?

Comment: @dtryon: No. It's from `AttributeRouting`. It should be `[PUT(...)]`.

Comment: I had this problem - it was because my controller action wasn't setup properly - it was expecting a parameter I wasn't including.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Apparently, there is a known problem within `AttributeRouting` wherein the `HttpPut` methods are currently non-functional in ASP.NET Web API.

The [currently accepted workaround](https://github.com/mccalltd/AttributeRouting/issues/96) is add the appropriate verb onto the route until a proper fix comes along:

> Web API RC sealed a vital interface for route detection by the
>   underlying framework. Though the interface is now public, the change
>   won't be released until vNext. So here are some workarounds:
>
> - Use AR attributes in combination with HttpGet, HttpPost, HttpPut, or HttpDelete attributes from System.Web.Http:

```
[GET("some/url"), HttpGet]
public string Method1() {}

[PUT("some/url"), HttpPut]
public string Method2() {}

[POST("some/url"), HttpPost]
public string Method3() {}

[DELETE("some/url"), HttpDelete]
public string Method4() {}
```

Comment: was just about to write this, +1

Comment: @FilipW: It took me quite a while to find this. I placed a comment  on the link in my answer asking if it would be possible to better document this in the code (e.g. `ObsoleteException`). This is quite a confusing bug considering there's already two known completely unrelated issues that cause the same problem.

Answer (score 14):

Double check that you're using **[HttpPut]** from **System.Web.Http**.

Under some circumstances you can end up using the attribute from System.Web.Mvc.

This was resulting in 405s for us.

Comment: could you give me some more details?

Comment: @AlexJin the `HttpPut` attribute could be defined in multiple namespaces, they will be treated differently.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same error, and traced it to a custom route that I'd defined like so:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "SomeCall",
    routeTemplate: "api/somecall/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "SomeCall", action = "Get" }
);
```

The problem here is the **`action = "Get"`** which prevented the `PUT` action of the same URI to respond. Removing the default action fixed the issue.

Comment: Thanks @MikeBantegui. In researching the problem, your question was the most comprehensive and closest match to my configuration - excepting the Attribute Routing - so I thought I'd put up my solution in case it helps someone else

Comment: Fair enough. Do you have any idea why the default action was preventing the `PUT` action? It seems like that may be a bug.

Comment: I wondered if it might be a bug too - it can't really be called 'defaults' if the actual Request method can't superceed it! Though I admit that I haven't looked into the reason why

Answer (score 3):

What worked for me was to add a Route Attribute as I already had one defined for a GET request that was overloaded as below:

```
    // GET api/Transactions/5
    [Route("api/Transactions/{id:int}")]
    public Transaction Get(int id)
    {
        return _transactionRepository.GetById(id);
    }

    [Route("api/Transactions/{code}")]
    public Transaction Get(string code)
    {
        try
        {
            return _transactionRepository.Search(p => p.Code == code).Single();
        }
        catch (Exception Ex)
        {
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Users\Public\ErrorLog\Log.txt",
                Ex.Message + Ex.StackTrace + Ex.Source + Ex.InnerException.InnerException.Message);
        }

        return null;
    }
```

So I added for the PUT:

```
    // PUT api/Transactions/5
    [Route("api/Transactions/{id:int}")]
    public HttpResponseMessage Put(int id, Transaction transaction)
    {
        try
        {
            if (_transactionRepository.Save(transaction))
            {
                return Request.CreateResponse<Transaction>(HttpStatusCode.Created, transaction);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception Ex)
        {
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Users\Public\ErrorLog\Log.txt",
                Ex.Message + Ex.StackTrace + Ex.Source + Ex.InnerException.InnerException.Message);
        }

        return Request.CreateResponse<Transaction>(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, transaction);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is no more the case, perhaps this issue has been fixed now. ASP.NET MVC Web API now allows $http.put and here is the code to test.

**AngularJS Script code**

```
$scope.UpdateData = function () {
        var data = $.param({
            firstName: $scope.firstName,
            lastName: $scope.lastName,
            age: $scope.age
        });

        $http.put('/api/Default?'+ data)
        .success(function (data, status, headers) {
            $scope.ServerResponse = data;
        })
        .error(function (data, status, header, config) {
            $scope.ServerResponse =  htmlDecode("Data: " + data +
                "\n\n\n\nstatus: " + status +
                "\n\n\n\nheaders: " + header +
                "\n\n\n\nconfig: " + config);
        });
    };
```

**Html code**

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="HttpPutController">
<h2>AngularJS Put request </h2>
<form ng-submit="UpdateData()">
    <p>First Name: <input type="text" name="firstName" ng-model="firstName" required /></p>
    <p>Last Name: <input type="text" name="lastName" ng-model="lastName" required /></p>
    <p>Age : <input type="number" name="age" ng-model="age" required /></p>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    <hr />
    {{ ServerResponse }}
</form></div>
```

**ASP.NET MVC Web API Controller action method**

```
 public class DefaultController : ApiController
{

    public HttpResponseMessage PutDataResponse(string firstName, string lastName, int age)
    {
        string msg =  "Updated: First name: " + firstName +
            " | Last name: " + lastName +
            " | Age: " + age;

        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, msg);
    }
}
```

(Change the url to send request to)
When we click on the Submit button, it sends HttpPut request to '/api/default' (DefaultController) where PutDataResponse action method is declared. This method will be called and user gets its response.

This solution was originally written [here](http://techfunda.com/Howto/angularjs/573/http-put-server-request)

Answer (score 0):

For me it was because I had not set the media type in the json content string for my http client request:

new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF32, **"application/json"**);

All sorts of weird behavior if this is not set.

Answer (score -1):

in my case I put in postman a parameter id:

```sh
http://localhost:55038/api/documento/pruebadetallecatalogo?id=100
```

but, I changed the url request to:

```sh
http://localhost:55038/api/documento/pruebadetallecatalogo/100
```

that works for me!!!