# HTTP Error 405 - Method Not Allowed

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis

I am having a really hard time solving this issue. I am using PUT verb to invoke controller action. I get the following error:

```
{"Message":"The requested resource does not support http method 'PUT'."}
```

Further digging found the following:

```
Module Name: WebDAVModule 
Notification: MapRequestHandler 
Handler: WebDAV
Requested URL: localhost/,..... (some url) 
Physical Path: C:\Projects\.... \order\sample
```

In the IIS settings I can see that the WebDAVModule is set to have PUT verb in a list of verbs but still I get the error. What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE:**

I even tried to decorate the controller's action with [Route] attribute but there is no such thing as [Route] attribute. VS is not able to find anything related to [Route] attribute.

Comment: Check the answer here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14321988/http-put-not-allowed-in-asp-net-web-api

Comment: In the link you provided they mention to place a PUT on the action. There is no such thing as PUT. There is HttpPut but that does not take any arguments.

Comment: Check this link:http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/774807/Attribute-Routing-in-ASP-NET-MVC-WebAPI

Comment: I am using ASP.NET 4.5