# ASP HTTPClient + AngularJs (update)

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, httpclient

I use HttpClient with ASP to consume services in a remote database
In my ASP controller (Collaborateur), I have the following code:

```js
        public Boolean UpdateCollaborateur(Collaborateur collaborateur) {

            using (var client = new HttpClient()) {

                (.......)
            }
            return true;

        }
```

Then in my angular service, i have the following call:

```js
.factory('UpdateCollaborateur', function ($http) {
    var fac = {};
    fac.Update = function (collaborateur) {
        return $http.put('/Collaborateur/UpdateCollaborateur/'+collaborateur);

    };
    return fac;
})
```

By putting a breakpoint , why i can not  access in my function UpdateCollaborateur after executing my method in my controller angularjs?
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may be wrong but shouldn't it be:
`return $http.put('/Collaborateur/UpdateCollaborateur/', collaborateur);`

You have a `+` instead of a `,`.

You also likely need the `[HttpPut]` attribute on the method.

NOTE: [HTTP PUT not allowed in ASP.NET Web API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14321988/http-put-not-allowed-in-asp-net-web-api)

Comment: another related question, how do I do if I want to pass two or multiple parameter in my fonction

Comment: Add them to the collaborateur model or add them to the query string ie. `/Collaborateur/UpdateCollaborateur/1` then update routing and the method `UpdateCollaborateur(int id, Collaborateur collaborateur)`