# HTTP PUT is not working in ASP.NET Web API

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-routing

I have simple Web API controller in which `GET` and `POST` are working but `PUT` and `DELETE` is not working. Server throws `The requested resource does not support http method 'PUT'` error when accessing PUT and DELETE
Here is how **web.config** looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <configuration>
        <configSections>
            <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
        </configSections>
        <system.web>
            <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2">
                <assemblies>
                    <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
                </assemblies>
            </compilation>
            <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" />
            <httpModules>
                <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
            </httpModules>
        </system.web>
        <system.webServer>
            <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
            <modules>
                <remove name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" />
                <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" preCondition="managedHandler" />
            </modules>
            <handlers>
                <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />      
                <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
            </handlers>
        </system.webServer>
        <runtime>
            <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
                <dependentAssembly>
                    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
                    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
                </dependentAssembly>
                <dependentAssembly>
                    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
                    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
                </dependentAssembly>
            </assemblyBinding>
        </runtime>
        <system.codedom>
            <compilers>
                <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
                <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
            </compilers>
        </system.codedom>    
    </configuration>
```

**Code for Global.asax**

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
}
```

**Code for Web API Configuration**

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{Id}",
            defaults: new { Id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

**And the controller has...**

```
public class GroupsController : ApiController
{
    [System.Web.Http.HttpPut]
    public ActionResult Put(int Id, [FromBody]Group NewGroup)
    {
        //some code here
    }
}
```

I have also looked into online resource but none of those are helping out...
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14321988/http-put-not-allowed-in-asp-net-web-api) and [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/93424/how-to-enable-put-and-delete-in-iis7)

I'm trying to make this API working in developer machine (IIS express/compact one that ships with Visual Studio).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that you not pass id as url part. For example "put /api/Groups" will return this error, but "put  /api/Groups/1" must work correctly.

Comment: Doing that throws different exception...
{
    "Message": "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:21331/api/Groups/1'.",
    "MessageDetail": "No action was found on the controller 'Groups' that matches the request."
}

Comment: Are you sure that you  not reconfigure routing or not changed Id name in Action? Typically this error occurs when in routing optional parameter with one name but in controller name is different. For example  routing configuration set Id parameter, but in action you set GroupId. For example with routing configuration that you posted action public ActionResult Put(int GroupId, [FromBody]Group NewGroup) will throw this error.

Comment: I installed help page nuget package and that helped me and the answer selected here is quite close to it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into the default route

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

> routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",

The {action} is missing from your config.

and API, for reference :

```
[HttpPut]
public IHttpActionResult Hero(int Id)
```

#### The Below API Call works

> http://localhost:48613/api/SuperHumans/Hero/1

#### The Below API Call WON'T work as the API route won't match

> http://localhost:48613/api/SuperHumans/Hero

Also make sure you are passing correct content type from the client

## EDIT -2

> REST API

```
[System.Web.Http.HttpPut]
public void Put(int id, Dummy value)
{

}
```

> Property Class

```
public class Dummy
{
    public string key1 { get; set; }
    public string key2 { get; set; }
}
```

> POSTMAN REST CALL

[image: POSTMAN REST CALL]

#### Debugger

[image]

Comment: {action} is missing because that's how REST is supposed to work... A URL and HTTP VERB. Actions are not made publicly know.

Comment: I'm not accepting this answer because of a reason that {action} should not be part of your URL when designing REST services else it looses the conventions.