# Angular post, put, delete returns 405

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, angularjs-http

I am new to angular.

I cant invoke POST, PUT and DELETE methods using angular (GETs working fine)
I have a .NET WebApi server which all methods and all resources URLs works and tested using Advanced Rest Client.

This is the code:

```
$scope.updateUser = function() {

    var url = 'http://localhost/api/users/' + $scope.selectedId;
    $http.put(url, $scope.user,{'content-type' : 'application/json'})
        .then(
            function(response) {
                alert("1");
            },
            function(errResponse) {
                alert("2");
            }
        );
};
```

I tried with 'content-type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', I tried with no config at all, I tried the one with success and error and I tried the one whith command and data attributes.

I get nothing back and while debugging, errResponse contains only the request data. Checked the network tab in the developer tools, and I found that 405 returned.
Again, all URLs are valid and tested using a third party REST client app.

Can any one help?

EDIT:
web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
    <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
  </modules>
  <httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
    </customHeaders>
  </httpProtocol>
  </system.webServer>
```

PUT example:

```
    [HttpPut]
    [Route("api/users/{id}")]
    public IHttpActionResult updateUser(int id, User user)
```

Regards,
Ido

Comment: Share the API methods, the web.config, portions of your global.asax. You have given very little code to go off of.

Comment: Is your `[HttpPut]` attribute from `System.Web.Http`? (Not from `System.Web.Mvc`)

Comment: Added web.config and an example

Comment: yes. System.Web.Http

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/a/14322875/752527

Comment: I get compilation errors at PUT.  I have only HttpPUT no simple PUT attribute.

Comment: If you get error 405 it looks like the verb is not allowed.
In the web.config for the ExtensionlessUrlHandler
Instead of verv="*" maybe something like verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS"

Comment: No... It didn't work. But the services are working... just not from angular

Comment: Maybe replacing $http.put(url, $scope.user, ...
by $http.put(url, { user: $scope.user}, ...

Comment: No.  Nl even tried with no user passing {}. I just want to catch it in the server

Answer (score 0):

adding this snippet to web.config should resolve problem :

```
<system.webServer>
   <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
       <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
   </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: No.. it didn't. I am capable of getting to these URLs... just not from angular.